# Python 2.7 urllib2 returns SSLv3 handshake failure

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

I have Python 2.7.9 on Mac OS 10.10. When I tried using urllib2, it gives the SSLv3 handshake failure. Here is the following code that I had tried:

```
URLaccess_token = "https://<some_pony_website>.net/oauth/access_token"
values = dict(grant_type="authorization_code", code=code, redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:5000", client_id="<secret_id>", client_secret="<seriously_this_is_a_secret>")
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(URLaccess_token, data)
rsp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content = rsp.read()
return content
```

This produces the following error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3  
alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:581)>
```

What is the solution to this problem?